# Filter model with serializer.validated_data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am setting up a Django REST application where peopple can review restaurants. So far I have those models:

```
class RestaurantId(models.Model):
    maps_id = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        

class RestaurantReview(models.Model):    
    review_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    

class StarterPics(models.Model):
    restaurant_review_id = models.OneToOneField(RestaurantReview,
                                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pics_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)    
    picture_1 = models.ImageField()
```

My serializers:

```
class RestaurantIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantId
        field = fields = '__all__'


class RestaurantReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantReview
        field = fields = '__all__'


class StarterPicsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StarterPics
        fields = '__all__'

   def validate_restaurant_review_id(self, value)
        if value.review_author != self.request.user:                
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User has not reviewed the restaurant")        
        return value
```

My views:

```
class RestaurantIdViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantId.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantIdSerializer

class RestaurantReviewViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantReview.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(review_author=self.request.user)

class StarterPicsViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.StarterPics.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StarterPicsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

I have set up permissions as well so only the review_author can update his reviews and pics_author can update his pictures.

My permissions:

```
class IsOwnReviewOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.pics_author == request.user


class IsAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

    return obj.review_author == request.user
```

Now what I have is that posting a StarterPics on a review that someone is not the author is imposible. That is the behaviour I am looking for. But if the review author tries to do so I have this error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <RestaurantReview: 8>.
```

Here is my serializer.validated_data:

```
    OrderedDict([('name_1', 'Salade de saison'), ('picture_1', <InMemoryUploadedFile: fricoteurs_inside.jpeg (image/jpeg)>),
('name_2', ''), ('picture_2', None), ('lat_pic_2', None), ('lng_pic_2', None),
('shot_time_2', None), ('restaurant_review_id', <RestaurantReview: 8>), ('pics_author', <User: pi>), ('restaurant_id', <RestaurantId: Les Fricoteurs>)])
```

Because I `cannot call .save() after accessing serializer.data` I can't get the `'restaurant_review_id': 4` I would have if I was using serializer.data.

So how can I filter my RestaurantReview model using serializer.validated_data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validation should be done in serializer [`field level`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation), not in `perform_create()` method:

```
class StarterPicsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def validate_resturant_review_id(self, value):
        if value.review_user != self.context['request'].user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User has not reviewed the resturant")
        return value
```

Comment: How can I adapt the code you gave me so the User can't POST a picture if he is not the author of the review?

Comment: Sorry, I got the opposite logic implemented. Add a not informant of the `if`. I have updated the answer

Comment: I tried your updates answer as edited in my question but now I get a if `value.review_author != request.user:
NameError: name 'request' is not defined` error.

Comment: The code i shared in answer is 'self.request.user'.

Comment: Now I have `AttributeError: 'StarterPicsSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: I opened a new question for filtering the restaurant_id:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048714/field-lookup-in-drf-serializer-validation